# Update one field with value from another field in a table where the field values themselves are keys

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join

I'm trying to make this select statement into an UPDATE statement:

```
SELECT a.option_value, b.option_value
FROM mydb.wp_options a
JOIN mydb.wp_options b 
WHERE a.option_name = "siteurl"
AND b.option_name = "home"
```

Where I simply want the a.option_value = b.option_value

I suspect this would be done via a subquery based on a join.  The structure is this:

```
col names: option_id, option_name, option_value
values:  1, siteurl, "http://dev.domain.com/"
values:  2, home, "http://www.domain.com"
```

so I want to replace the option_name = "siteurl" option_value = "dev.domain.com" field with another domain field as referrenced by the value in option_name = "home" and its corresponding option_value="http://www.domain.com".

So it would then look like:

```
col names: option_id, option_name, option_value
values:  1, siteurl, "http://www.domain.com"
values:  2, home, "http://www.domain.com"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can very simply achieve this with the multiple-table update syntax:

```
UPDATE mydb.wp_options a, mydb.wp_options b 
SET    a.option_value = b.option_value
WHERE  a.option_name  = "siteurl"
   AND b.option_name  = "home"
```

Or else, use a subquery (no join required):

```
UPDATE mydb.wp_options
SET    option_value = (
  SELECT option_value
  FROM   mydb.wp_options
  WHERE  option_name = "home"
)
WHERE  option_name  = "siteurl"
```